# Fixed on scroll with Sticky-kit

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use [Sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) on a webpage, where the sidebar needs to be fixed on scroll. It works as it should, but I have used negative margin (-548px) on the sidebar, so it first gets fixed when it reaches the original position.

How can I fix this?

**CSS on the sidebar**

```
.sidebar {
    margin-top: -548px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".sidebar").stick_in_parent();
```

**HTML markup**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 sidebar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [link](http://ssg.siteworks.dk/sw/frontend/show.asp?parent=481963&layout=0) to the webpage, so you can see it in action. The sidebar is the one on the right, up in the banner.

Comment: Have you tried with the "offset_top" option property described in the docs?